# Below a socket meaning

Tags: word-choice

What does "immediately below the socket" and "circuit" in the second sentence mean?
(From Fast Heater instruction manual)

1. "The heater should not be plugged in immediately below a socket."
2. "This heater should be plugged into its own 220-240 V circuit."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugging in a room heater and placing it against a wall immediately below a socket on that wall would risk damaging the socket by heat from rising hot air (they often have casings or inside parts made of plastic). Whoever wrote the instructions may not have been a native English speaker. The meaning is 'do not plug in the heater and locate it directly below any socket, whether the socket into which it is plugged, or another'. Or, indeed, when it is directly below any other thing that could be damaged by heat.

Most heater instructions contain such an item

> Do not locate the heater immediately below a fixed socket outlet or
> connection box.
>
> Do not locate the heater immediately below a socket outlet.
>
> The appliance is not to be located directly below an electrical wall
> socket.
>
> DO NOT place the heater directly below a fixed socket outlet.
>
> The appliances should not be installed directly under a wall power
> socket.

In the USA and certain other countries, electricity is supplied by separate "branch" circuits leading from the breaker or fuse box. There will be some '110-120 volt' circuits, and some '220-240 volt' circuits. The latter are used for higher power items such as cooking stoves, air conditioning units, water heaters, etc. The Fast Heater must only be plugged into a socket fed by a circuit of the latter type, and also, it must not share that circuit with any other appliance, so that there is no danger of overheating of wires, blown fuses, or tripped circuit breakers.

Comment: I am plugging it into the socket not below the socket. This is the part I don't understand.
.

Comment: Could you please explain once again?

Comment: @AntoniaA - I have edited the answer.

Comment: How do I plug in the heater when it's directly below the socket? It's in the socket not below it. Does it mean not to  plug in the heater upside down to avoid hot air reaching the socket?

Comment: Why does it say "below"?

Comment: thanks! I have just read it.  You saved my house from fire:)